# How can I build multiple targets using cmake --build

Tags: cmake

I have a CMake build with a bunch of different targets `A`, `B`, `C`, etc.
An external application is tasked with building, and currently does so by calling

```
cmake --build .
```

However, this builds *all* targets, and sometimes I only want to build a subset, like `A` and `B` but not `C`.
The `--target` flag can only be given once, and only accepts a single target.

I guess I could let CMake generate the appropriate Makefile, and then call `make A B` explicitly, but that takes away the nice thing about `cmake --build` being build system agnostic.

Is there a nice way to solve this?

Comment: Are you okay with running the configure and generation steps every time you want to build a different subset of targets? If yes, then the answer is pretty simple. By "configure and generation" I mean something like `cmake -H<src_dir> -B<bin_dir>`, or a more traditional `cmake ..` from `<bin_dir>`.

Comment: You could add another custom target with dependencies to e.g. `A` and `B`. But no, there is no command line option to build multiple targets given as a list.

Comment: Forgot to mention that you could also define which targets are included in `ALL` with [`EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL.html) directory/target properties.

Comment: @light2yellow I already run a configure/generate step before each build at this point, so that's not a problem. Can you be more specific in how that would help me?

Comment: @Florian No, I don't want to have to specify custom targets since the combinations required would be large and annoying.

Comment: Yes, I posted an example as an answer

Answer (score 35):

CMake version 3.15 added support for this feature. Simply list all targets on the command line as follows:

```
cmake --build . --target Library1 Library2
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not the "nicest" way, but definitely a solution would be to introduce a custom top-level target and make the needed targets depend on it. For example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9) # can be lower

project(demo LANGUAGES C)

file(WRITE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/a.c"
    [[
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(void) { printf("a\n"); return 0; }
    ]])
file(WRITE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/b.c"
    [[
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(void) { printf("b\n"); return 0; }
    ]])
file(WRITE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/c.c"
    [[
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(void) { printf("c\n"); return 0; }
    ]])

add_executable(A "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/a.c")
add_executable(B "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/b.c")
add_executable(C "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/c.c")

set(DEMO_ENABLE_TARGETS "" CACHE
    STRING "Targets to be built in demo simultaneously (default: none)")

if(NOT "${DEMO_ENABLE_TARGETS}" STREQUAL "")
    add_custom_target(enabled_targets)
    foreach(target IN LISTS DEMO_ENABLE_TARGETS)
        add_dependencies(enabled_targets ${target})
    endforeach()
endif()
```

Then invoke

```
$ cmake -H. -Bbuild -DDEMO_ENABLE_TARGETS="B;C"
$ cmake --build build --target enabled_targets
```

and only `B` and `C` will be built.

Note that you have to specify `DEMO_ENABLE_TARGETS`'s contents as a list, otherwise it'll break.