# build multiple targets in make command line

Tags: makefile

Suppose I have a make file, and I have many target `MyTarget1,MyTarget2,MyTarget3,...,MyTarget100`.

If I want compile all targets using 12 thread, I can simply using `make -j12 all`.

Now I want compile a subset of all target, suppose `MyTarget1, MyTarget2, MyTarget3, MyTarget4`.

I know that compile each target one by one must work. In this way, 12 thread work on `MyTarget1`, wait, work on `MyTarget2`, wait, ... If `MyTarget` do not have a high parallism, for example it is a small target like helloworld, some thread's time is wasted. I do not like it for its low parallism.

I want a high parallism solution, like `make -j12 all`, which 12 thread can work on different target at a certain moment.

How can I implement that?

I want something like

```
make -j12 MyTarget1,MyTarget2,MyTarget3,MyTarget4
```

#### Reference

follow link already given the `CMake`'s solution, now I am wondering can it be implement directly using `make`.

- [How can I build multiple targets using cmake --build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47553569/how-can-i-build-multiple-targets-using-cmake-build)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: doesn't `make -j12 MyTarget1 MyTarget2 MyTarget3 MyTarget4` fit your need ?

Comment: @ymonad In your suggestion, the make do follow: using 12 thread compile MyTarget1, wait it finished. Then using 12 thread compile MyTarget2, wait,... In this way, 12 thread work on same target at a certain moment. It just like the one by one solution. It do not have high parallelism as `make -j12 all`. In `make -j12 all` 12 thread can work on different target at a certain moment.

Comment: I think @ymonad is correct. I have done a simple experiment that confirms it (at least with GNU Make  3.81).

Comment: @Beta ymonad's solution dose wok. But is seems like the one by one solution. I wonder is there exist any high parallelism solution.

Comment: My experiment confirms that ymonad's solution works *with high parallelism.* I urge you to conduct the experiment.

Comment: My makefile is generated by cmake. I have tried to test it, but it seems just like the one by one solution.@Beta

Comment: I believe this is a CMake limitation. Some of those generated Makefiles did include explicit `.NOPARALLEL` option when I worked with CMake.

Comment: @raspy sir, can I do some configure in CMakeLists.txt to break the limitation?

Comment: I don't really think so. CMake-generated Makefiles are quite convoluted, `Makefile` will call `CMakeFiles/Makefile2` as far as I remember. You *might* be lucky with calling this `Makefile2` directly, but preferably you would define custom target that calls a predefined subset of other targets (if it can be predefined and not totally random).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a limitation of `CMake`. Generated `Makefile` is explicitly listed to not run in parallel. For example:

```
$ cat CMakeLists.txt
project(foo C)

add_custom_target(target1 ALL
  COMMAND python3 -c "import time; time.sleep(5)"
  VERBATIM
  )

add_custom_target(target2 ALL
  COMMAND python3 -c "import time; time.sleep(5)"
  VERBATIM
  )
```

Relevant parts of generated `Makefile` are:

```
$ cat Makefile
...
# Allow only one "make -f Makefile2" at a time, but pass parallelism.
.NOTPARALLEL:
...
# The main all target
all: cmake_check_build_system
        $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /home/raspy/so-62013595/CMakeFiles /home/raspy/so-62013595/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
        $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
        $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /home/raspy/so-62013595/CMakeFiles 0
.PHONY : all
...
# Build rule for target.
target2: cmake_check_build_system
        $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 target2
.PHONY : target2
...
# Build rule for target.
target1: cmake_check_build_system
        $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 target1
.PHONY : target1
```

So as you can see every target is propagated to a sub-makefile, but since this top `Makefile` is listed as not parallel, it will not allow to build multiple targets at the same time.

```
$ make -j8 target1 target2 | ts
May 26 15:45:06 Built target target1
May 26 15:45:13 Built target target2    # <--- Built after target1 completed
```

For arbitrary targets, you might be successful with calling sub-makefile directly:

```
$ make -j8 -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 target1 target2 | ts
May 26 15:45:42 Built target target2
May 26 15:45:42 Built target target1    # <--- Built simultaneously with target2
```

YMMV though.

Comment: AFAICT [the issue](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=14312) that caused the current implementation is also why calling Sub-Makefiles directly did not work for me (race when building common dependencies of targets). If you can, just use the ninja generator. Parallel builds of multiple targets work flawlessly for me with a CMake-generated ninja project.