GCC fails when multiple different versions are needed in makefile
I have a makefile that needs to use 2 different versions of GCC so as to output different executables in the same invocation. Specifically, I'm using one that targets old 32-bit Windows computers and one that targets much more recent computers. Unfortunately switches such as -m32 etc. by themselves do not cut it and I really do need 2 different versions of GCC.
I get strange errors when I add both versions to PATH and call them directly in the makefile. This was theorised as being attributable to GCC's modular design. The basic idea of my makefile is as follows:
GCC_32 = i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
GCC_64 = x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc

win_32_bit: $(COMMON_REQUIREMENTS_NOT_IN_EXAMPLE)
    $(GCC_32) -mwindows -m32 -march=pentium $^ old_main_file.cpp -static-libstdc++ $(LIBS_NOT_IN_EXAMPLE) -o old.exe
win_64_bit: $(COMMON_REQUIREMENTS_NOT_IN_EXAMPLE)
    $(GCC_64) -mwindows -m64 -march=core2 $^ new_main_file.cpp -static-libstdc++ $(LIBS_NOT_IN_EXAMPLE) -o new.exe

If I were to instead remove all references to GCC from PATH and then hardcode the paths in, the code then works.
GCC_32 = /mingw32/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
GCC_64 = /mingw64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc

# The rest is the same

Obviously, hard-coding paths is bad and not portable. I'd rather find out why there's a conflict and write a makefile that deals with it. Perhaps there's a way to e.g. hide the other compiler from each other or perhaps glean the paths from PATH, remove them, and inject them in to the makefile

Is there any possibility someone could tell me what's wrong with my question

I guess your question was already answered. I would recommend to use a makefile generator like CMake. There you can define 2 build targets for your compilers. For instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47553569/how-can-i-build-multiple-targets-using-cmake-build

To help beyond just guessing, readers would need to see, at least, an MRE demonstrating
the problem including the operative PATH and verbatim build log.

Agree with @MikeKinghan.  There is not enough detail here.  For example, you should go look at the contents of the two bin directories on your PATH.  Is there an instance of i686-w64-mingw32-gcc or x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc in both of them?  If so that's the issue.  Run which i686-w64-mingw32-gcc and which x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc in your makefile and make sure the paths are correct (maybe the makefile is changing PATH).  It's just not true that the front-end will get confused about which backend to use (unless you or MinGW is doing something weird).

You can also invoke the compiler with the -v option to see what the ACTUAL paths and commands for the backends are, then compare them when run with and without the fully-qualified path.  Maybe that will give some insight.

You can ask the shell to compute the paths for you:
GCC_32 := $(shell which i686-w64-mingw32-gcc) 
GCC_64 := $(shell which x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc)

But that is only masking the problem of it not working without absolute paths...

That's a rather elegant solution, actually. Wish I have of thought of that. Of course I'll also need to remove them from PATH after this, but I suspect that'll just be a delimited string search for "gcc" (in case there are also more)

You should remove $(dirname $(GCC_x))  from PATH to be precise.

I ended up having to use this monstrosity: export PATH := $(shell echo $(PATH) | tr ":" "\n" | grep -v -e $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $(GCC_32))) -e $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $(GCC_64))) | tr "\n" ":")

which is not a standard utility.  On systems that provide it, that is often in the form of a shell function, which could present difficulties under some circumstances.  The command type -p command-name is a more standard way of getting the wanted information.
